# Difference between "fsck -y" vs "fsck -a"

Tags: linux, fsck

What is the difference between -a and -y parameters of linux fsck? man page does not show me the difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

man e2fsck

was more explanatory.

-a : will do noninteractive fsck. however it may encounter some errors that requires user intervention and exits with a value more then 2. The admin should run and correct the error

-y : will do interactive fsck but with "yes" for all questions. This is like a noninteractive fsck in this manner. however it will correct all errors.

Comment: The correct response to nearly any fsck issue is 'y' anyway.